# Xamarin call async function from override that returns value

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, async-await

The basic setup here is I have platform independent code that makes REST calls and then calls event handlers registered by the platform specific UI code if something changed that needs to update the UI.  Those event handlers must execute on the UI thread.  This all seems pretty straightforward for void calls but situations like this I'm not sure if I'm doing this right:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app,
                                       NSDictionary options) {
    /* Setup code removed */
    Task task = BackendService.DoSomethingAsync();
    return (true);
}
```

That's in the iOS application delegate.  Is that the proper way to call that async task and making sure not to hold up the UI while it's running? It seems to work but I'm not sure if it will blow up randomly down the line.

Comment: Do you call `FinishedLaunching`? That code will start the `async` operation and immediately return without you ever knowing the result.

Comment: The OS calls FinishedLaunching when the app starts.  I just need to kick off the call that queries the web services.  I'm just not sure what happens without the await on the task.

Comment: It will call your webservice and return. If you don't care whether your call has succeeded or not, then you can keep the code in there, if you do care about the result, then you will have to sync call your webservice or do it somewhere else.

Comment: What method needs to read the value returned from FinishedLaunching? How is the Boolean interpreted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an event handler

```
private event EventHandler LaunchFinished = delegate { };
```

then subscribe and raise the event in the `FinishedLaunching` method.

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options) {
    // subscribe to event with event handler
    LaunchFinished += LaunchFinishedHandler;
    // raise event
    LaunchFinished(this, EventArgs.Empty);        
    return (true);
}
```

the event handler can be awaited so it does not block the UI thread

```
private async void LaunchFinishedHandler(object sender, EventArgs args) {
    LaunchFinished -= LaunchFinishedHandler; //optional

    // Setup code removed for brevity

    //On UI Thread

    await BackendService.DoSomethingAsync(); //non blocking await

    //Back on UI thread
}
```

event handlers are the one case where `async void` are allowed. Using this pattern will also allow you to catch any exception that may arise out of invoking the async function.

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a "fire and forget" async feature, try this;

```
public static class TaskExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>       
        /// It is used when you want to call an async method without
        /// awaiting for it. Using this method suppresses the warning CS4014.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="task">Task to be called using a fire-and-forget call</param>
        public static void Forget(this Task task)
        {
            task.ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
```

then you can use it by;

```
YourActionName().Forget();
```